# storing value into .edmx table

Tags: c#, edmx

I'm trying to store a value that is an int into a table, but I keep getting the message "cannot implicitly convert string to int" if I change the table datatype from int32 to string then I get this message http://postimg.org/image/cv1cc4jkf/full/
Can anyone help me resolve this issue? easyScoreLabel, mediumScoreLabel, and highScoreLabel are labels I dragged onto the web application from the toolbox.

```
    protected void myScoresButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (projectDBEntities1 dbcontext = new projectDBEntities1())
        {
          message aMessage = new message();
        aMessage.userName = nameTextBox.Text;
        aMessage.highScoreEasy = Int32.Parse(easyScoreLabel.Text);
        aMessage.highScoreMedium = Int32.Parse(mediumScoreLabel.Text);
        aMessage.highScoreHard = Int32.Parse(hardScoreLabel.Text);
        dbcontext.messages.Add(aMessage);
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();

        }

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Read the error message closely/again. It *says* what the problem is. Exactly what line is it referring to? What is the line (incorrectly) trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

easyScoreLabel.Text is the string. You need to convert it to the int.

```
aMessage.highScoreEasy = Int.Parse(easyScoreLabel.Text);
aMessage.highScoreMedium = Int.Parse(mediumScoreLabel.Text);
aMessage.highScoreHard = Int.Parse(hardScoreLabel.Text);
```